# What is the purpose of GWT.create with RPC services?

Tags: java, gwt, binding, rpc

What is the purpose of GWT.create() in terms of RPC services? I understand that it allows for deferred binding, but haven't managed to clearly understand how that applies to RPC services within my GWT application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT automatically generates an RPC implementation from a `RemoteService` interface and it's corresponding `Async` interface. `GWT#create()` is the glue between your application and the concrete implementation(s) created by GWT's code generators.

Comment: So GWT auto-generates a class to which the GWT.create object is bound at compile time?

Comment: GWT generates a concrete implementation of your Async RPC interface, yes. GWT.create gives you a handle to an instance of that implementation.

Comment: Thanks Jason, helped there :)